# Scale down kubernetes job but dont delete pods until complete

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible To scale down a kubernetes jobs parallelism value but leave any running jobs up until they have run to completion.

I have a specific scenario where I am running vsts build agents in containers and need to design the solution in such a way that there is always one agent available at all times. Scaling up is easy as this can just be done at the start of every build however because I need to  clean up the agent before the pod finishes I cant scale down in the same way at the end of the build. If there were a way to set the target parallelism but not delete any pods until one completed this would be perfect but any other way for me to achieve this or pointers on where to look would be great.

Comment: What do you mean saying "I need to clean up the agent before the pod finishes" ?

Comment: @mk_sta If i don't remove the agent before removing the pod then i have no way to get rid of the agent except manually deleting it in vsts. This causes an issue as we can only have a certain amount of agents based on the msdn licences we have and so if agents are left undeleted and new ones continue to be created then we will run out of space at some point

Comment: Are you looking for "Parallel Jobs with a work queue": https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/? It seems there is noting we can do on VSTS side?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your goal is not to be accomplished out of Kubernetes box because in [Parallel Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) implementation it is feasible to have a Pod after completion available.  Usually to specify Job scenario we use conditions like `.spec.completions` or `.spec.parallelism` but they are only tracked for completion of Pods and execution in parallel.

Take a look at this [Article](http://jessicadeen.com/tech/microsoft/how-to-deploy-to-kubernetes-using-helm-and-vsts/) and [GitHub Project](https://github.com/Azure/helm-vsts-agent) for the deployment of `VSTS` agents using `Helm` on Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but **for future reference:**

using KEDA you can run VSTS/Azure DevOps build agents as `ScaledJob` instead of regular deployments. This means a new ADO agent is created for each queued ADO job and is destroyed afterwards. This solves the issue where pods are scaled in while they are still running a job, thus interrupting the build/release.

More information: https://keda.sh/blog/2021-05-27-azure-pipelines-scaler/#run-the-self-hosted-agent-as-a-job

Basically you would have a .yaml like this:

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledJob
metadata:
  name: azdevops-scaledjob
spec:
  jobTargetRef:
    template:
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: azdevops-agent-job
          image: <azdevops-image>
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
          - name: AZP_URL
            value: "<organizationUrl>"
          - name: AZP_TOKEN
            value: "<token>"
          - name: AZP_POOL
            value: "<agentpool>"
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
            name: docker-volume
        volumes:
        - name: docker-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/docker.sock
  pollingInterval: 30
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  maxReplicaCount: 10   
  scalingStrategy:
    strategy: "default"               
  triggers:
  - type: azure-pipelines
    metadata:
      poolID: "1"
      organizationURLFromEnv: "AZP_URL"
      personalAccessTokenFromEnv: "AZP_TOKEN"
```

Note that you need a little hack to trick Azure Devops into running a build on an agent pool that has no agents in it (since you wouldn't have an agent idling when there are no jobs to run). It boils down to having a disabled agent in the pool that stays there and does nothing (it does not even have to be up and running).
https://keda.sh/blog/2021-05-27-azure-pipelines-scaler/#placeholder-agent

For this placeholder agent you would update the entrypoint script provided by Microsoft so that the agent is not destroyed after it finishes its job:

```
cleanup() { 
  if [ -e config.sh ]; then 
    if [ -z "$AZP_PLACEHOLDER" ]; then 
      print_header "Cleanup. Removing Azure Pipelines agent..." 

      # If the agent has some running jobs, the configuration removal process will fail. 
      # So, give it some time to finish the job. 
      while true; do 
        ./config.sh remove --unattended --auth PAT --token $(cat "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE") && break 

        echo "Retrying in 30 seconds..." 
        sleep 30 
      done 
    else 
      print_header "Cleanup skipped as Agent is marked as a placeholder... this option should be removed if Azure DevOps allows queueing to empty Agent Pools." 
    fi 
  fi 
}
```

Taken from here: https://github.com/kedacore/keda/discussions/2649#discussioncomment-2432405